# Call and implement PHP+javascript code by using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have Mixed Code php + (vanilla javascript) Inside php file .
I called the code inside this file by ajax .

**Example of the php code**

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
  alert('Hello')
</script>";
```

The problem is that PHP code is executed, but the JavaScript code is not executed .

Is there a solution for the implementation the two codes PHP + JS using ajax request

**Please i want vanilla javascript example not any javascript framework**

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown how you are calling this PHP script with AJAX. When you receive the response of the server you need to inject it somewhere into the DOM in order for the script to get included and executed.

For example if you are using jQuery you could use the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/foo.php',
    success: function(result) {
        $('body').append(result);
    }
});
```

or you could directly have your PHP script return javascript (without the `<script>` tags):

```
echo "alert('Hello')";
```

and then use the [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) method:

```
$.getScript('/foo.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server-side and JavaScript is client-side. If you execute an AJAX request to a PHP page, that page will render its PHP and send the result back as **text** (or XML or ...). It's up to the script receiving that output to figure out what to do with it.

In your case, most likely, you're getting a page like this from AJAX:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
alert('Hello')
</script>
```

This is stored as plain text and passed to the callback in your AJAX function. To deal with it, I would recommend some framework implementation of AJAX like [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.php",
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
    // Expected output - User alert saying
    // <script type='text/javascript'>
    // alert('Hello')
    // </script>
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should show the code of ajax call.

Are you using jquery?

This example may help you for javascript ajax

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/simple-ajax-php-and-javascript

http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajax-javascript.php

jquery ajax

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: i'm using Javascript itself or as it is called vanilla

Comment: Ok.Is the code you shown is in a seperate php page or not? how you call ajax?

Comment: i know ajax code this not my problem, i want to implementation of the javascript code after the call from the php file as I explained in the previous

Comment: did you check the first link!

Comment: yes i checked it, it explains how to make request by ajax only